# How to do recursive case statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have the following sample data and I want to add the column "sort_key" in the following order as shown below:

```
employee_ID first_name  last_name   Supervisor_ID   sort_key
580         Vick    White           583               3
585         Jonathan Brown          580               4
465         Jordan  Mistry          585               5
627         Rogan   Jacob           465               6
628         Tad     Max             465               6
583         Logan   Fi              81                2
81          Fara    Jake            8                 1
8           Raj     Xhi             NULL              0
```

Basically, I want to follow the logic that every employee's sort_key should be their supervisor's sort_key + 1. So the employee that doesn't have any supervisor (i.e., highest rank) will have a 0 sort_key, and then the employees under will get their sort_keys accordingly.

I'm trying to write the case statement but unable to understand what to write in the else clause:

```
Case
When supervisor_id = NULL then 0
Else
(...) + 1
End as sort_key
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A case statement alone won't do it efficiently.

In Postgresql, the thing you want is a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) (common table expression).

```
    WITH RECURSIVE sortedemployees(employee_ID, first_name, last_name, Supervisor_ID, sort_key) AS (
        SELECT e.employee_ID, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.Supervisor_ID, 0 sort_key
        FROM employees e
        WHERE e.Supervisor_ID IS NULL
      UNION ALL
        SELECT e.employee_ID, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.Supervisor_ID, s.sort_key + 1
        FROM employees e
        INNER JOIN sortedemployees s on e.Supervisor_ID = s.employee_ID
    )
    SELECT * FROM sortedemployees;
```

This example is similar to the "breadth-first search" example in the Postgresql documentation.